# How do i get the IsTrigger to work w/ StartStopComponents RPC?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having issues where the Box Collider is not wanting to trigger even with the IsTrigger checked as it's supposed to activate the RPC Shown Below. Everything else works, it's just this Trigger that's not wanting to trigger and everything is set up in order to make it work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeM7G.png)

I am not sure what i am doing wrong and the code for the RPC looks like it's supposed to trigger when the player's collider (which is a capsule collider and a rigidbody w/ no kinematics) is in the box collider.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZMNR.png)

i've tried adding colliders on the reference object, i've looked up everything in terms of how IsTrigger is supposed to work, but nothing worked.

Comment: It's really counterintuitive but the object receiving the trigger collision needs a rigidbody as well as a collider set to trigger. the body triggering the trigger needs to have a rigidbody and a collider set to not-trigger https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: I already fixed it! All i have to say that it was grade A Sierra adventure game moon logic!